# Aligning Two Tables in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to align two separate tables in html. I want them centered with one on the left, one on the right and some space between the tables. Here is the code I currently have set up. I have them aligned, but one is left and one is right with lots of space between them. New to Html please would be appreciated!

```
    <h1>
    Retrofit</h1>
    <p>
    Kendell Retrofit is the latest division to the Kendell divisions. Our Retrofit team includes customer service, outside sales, production and keying specialists.&nbsp;</p>
    <div>
    <table style="float:left">
    </table>
    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" style="width: 150px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align: left;">
                    Markets:<br />
                    &nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Commercial</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Financial</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Global</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Government</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Healthcare</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Higher Education</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            K-12 Education</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Retail</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div>
    <table style="float:right">
    </table>
    <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" style="width: 150px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align: left;">
                    <p>
                        Brands:</p>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Arrow</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Best</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Corbin Russwin</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Dorma</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Falcon</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Kwikset</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Sargent</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Schlage</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Stanley</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Weiser</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Yale</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<hr />
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: It might be stupid, but why not create a table with three cell? the first column become the first table, the middle the space, and the third the second table.

Comment: This isn't really answering the question, but why are you using tables at all? They don't seem the best solution here and the lists within the cells don't semantically make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic nested table will do it.

```
<table width="600px" >
    <tr>
       <td style="width: 50%;" >
          <table width="100%" >
             <tr>
                <td>
                   content of left side
                </td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td style="width: 50%;" >
          <table width="100%" >
             <tr>
                <td>
                   content of right side
                </td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Check it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xElsw)

Note: `margin: 0 auto;` makes your table at the center

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using float left/right use inline-table as shown below:

```
table
{
display:inline-table;
}
```

This way you can have tables side by side.

Comment: For some reason `inline-table` is shown as `inline`

Answer (score 0):

If you change the value of "style="width: 150px" by one more high (200px or 250px), does it work ?

Comment: or maybe deleting "style="width: 150px" ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to float the first table. Then you simply add `margin-right: 50px;` (for example) to it and the second one will be next to it, 50px away. If you want to center them both, put them in a div with some width and add `margin: 0 auto;`. [Here](http://jsbin.com/voqakiwe/3/) is a jsbin example.

P.S.: Press edit in top-right corner to see the code. The good thing about using this float to the first table, with 2 seperate tables and with `margin: 0 auto;` to the parent div is that it is responsive. Try resizing the browser window and you will see how the tables seperate on smaller resolutions (good for a website that is designed to run on smartphones too)

Answer (score 0):

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/00w1z44o/)

You can try on the second table :

```
<table style="float:left">
```

and replace on the second table :

```
align="right"
```

with

```
align="left"
```

Answer (score 0):

They are misaligned because you have `Markets:<br /> &nbsp;` in first table and `<p>Brands:</p>` in second table. You need to be consistent with them.

You can use `float:left;` and `margin-right` on the first div to get the spacing.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/goruquqi/1/edit?html,output) sample (Seems like Fiddle is down)